# Approximation of zonoids

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, convex-geometry, zonotopes

I have a question regarding the papers on approximating zonoids with zonotopes. I'll first write down the approximation problem and then state what my question is.

**Problem of Approximating Zonoids.** Suppose that $Z\subseteq \mathbb{R}^d$ is a given zonoid, having the origin as an interior point and center. What is the minimum number $N$ of summands of a zonotope needed to approximate $Z$ such that $Z\subseteq A\subseteq (1+\epsilon)Z$, where $A$ is the approximating zonotope?

**The Approach.** The approach taken by Bourgain and Lindenstrauss in [Distribution of points on spheres and approximation by zonotopes](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02767366) and Matoušek in [Improved upper bounds for approximation by zonotopes](http://doi.org/10.1007/BF02392598) starts with the following dual formulation: Let $\tau$ be a probability measure on $S^{d-1}$ (the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^d$), find $N$ points $\{z_j\}_{j=1}^N$ on $S^{d-1}$ and nonnegative scalars $\{\alpha_j\}_{j=1}^N$ such that
$$
\left\lvert \sum_{j=1}^N \alpha_j \lvert\langle z_i, x\rangle\rvert  - \int_{S^{d-1}} \lvert\langle z,x\rangle\rvert d\tau(z) \right\rvert < \epsilon, \quad \forall x\in S^{d-1}. \tag{$\ast$}\label{star}
$$
Exactly the same formulation was also recorded in the Handbook of the Geometry of Banach Spaces, Chapter 21, [Aspects of the Isometric Theory of Banach Spaces](https://doi.org/10.1016/S1874-5849(01)80023-1), by Koldobsky and König.

The papers then obtained the results of the form $N\leq c(d) (\epsilon^{-2}\log(1/\epsilon))^{1-O(1/d)}$; that is, the minimum number $N$ can be taken with no dependence on the given $Z$. The same bound works for all zonoids $Z$.

**My question**. It seems to me that the correct dual formulation should be $$
\left\lvert \sum_{j=1}^N \alpha_j \lvert\langle z_i, x\rangle\rvert  - \int_{S^{d-1}} \lvert\langle z,x\rangle\rvert d\tau(z) \right\rvert < \epsilon\int_{S^{d-1}} \lvert\langle z,x\rangle\rvert d\tau(z), \quad \forall x\in S^{d-1}
$$
instead of just $\epsilon$ on the right-hand side in \eqref{star}. The integral could be very small and should not be ignored if we want a uniform bound for all $Z$. Bourgain and Lindenstrauss's paper also discusses the case when $Z$ is the unit ball, in which case $\tau(z)$ is the uniform probability measure on $S^{d-1}$ and the integral $\int_{S^{d-1}} \lvert\langle z,x\rangle\rvert d\tau(z)$ is a constant depending only on $d$, so the integral can be omitted on the right-hand side, as what Bourgain and Lindenstrauss did. But for a general $Z$, I do not see why the integral can be omitted. A possible preprocessing is to transform $Z$ to a good position or shape via a linear transformation so the integral is always at least some constant (depending on $d$ only), but I am not sure how to do this. Can someone help explain why Bourgain and Lindenstrauss's paper and Matoušek's paper only need $\epsilon$ on the right-hand side in \eqref{star}?

===

**Update.** It seems that the following preprocessing works. For a zonoid, we find the maximal ellipsoid it contains, change it to the unit ball using a linear transformation, and thus we can assume that $B_{\ell_2}^d \subseteq Z \subseteq \sqrt{d}B_{\ell_2}^d$ by John's Theorem.

Then, consider the supporting function of $Z$, which is
$$
h(x) = \int_{S^{d-1}} |\langle z,x\rangle| d\lambda(z)
$$
for some measure $\lambda$ on $S^{d-1}$. Since $B_{\ell_2}^d \subseteq Z \subseteq \sqrt{d}B_{\ell_2}^d$, we have
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{d}} \leq h(x) \leq 1, \quad \forall x \in S^{n-1}.
$$
Now we need to normalize $\lambda$ to a probability measure and we need to show that $\int_{S^{n-1}} d\lambda(z)$ is bounded. This can be easily done by integrating the second inequality above over $S^{n-1}$, which leads to
$$
1 \geq \int_{S^{d-1}} h(x) dx = \int_{S^{d-1}} \left(\int_{S^{d-1}} |\langle z,x\rangle| dx\right) d\lambda(z) = \beta_d\int_{S^{d-1}} d\lambda(z),
$$
that is,
$$
\int_{S^{d-1}} d\lambda(z)\leq \frac{1}{\beta_d}
$$
and thus (letting $\tau$ be the normalized measure of $\lambda$)
$$
\int_{S^{d-1}} |\langle z,x\rangle| d\tau(z)\geq \frac{\beta_d}{\sqrt{d}},
$$
where the right-hand side is a constant depending on $d$ only.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the Koldobsky and König article [Aspects of the isometric theory of Banach spaces](https://doi.org/10.1016/S1874-5849(01)80023-1) you referenced is in [Handbook of the geometry of Banach spaces](https://www.sciencedirect.com/handbook/handbook-of-the-geometry-of-banach-spaces) (not in _Handbook of geometric functional analysis_), and edited accordingly.  If this was incorrect, then feel free to revert, and please pardon my wrong edit.

Comment: @LSpice Oh yes, you are correct, it's Handbook of Geometry of Banach Spaces. Thanks for the edits!